# Is there a way to make Zorn's lemma applicable when the upper bound property *just* fails, due to a "constant" chain?

Tags: relations, order-theory, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

Let $X,\preceq$ be a partially-ordered set such that every chain $x_n\preceq x_{n+1}\ldots$ has a limit in $\overline X$.

And let $\overline X,\preceq$ be a partially ordered set and a topological space.

But let $\overline X\setminus X$ be a single $\Bbb N$-indexed chain $x'$.

I wanted to apply Zorn's lemma to show that $x'$ is the maximal element.

However, here is where that objective fails:  while there is a valid chain $x'$ given by $x'_0,x'_1,\ldots$, and it has a limit in $\overline X$, the idea of every chain having an upper bound breaks down, because:

The chain $x'$, given by $x'_0,x'_1,\ldots$ converges to the limit point $x_0$.  Therefore on $\overline X,\preceq$ introducing the concept of a limit point of a chain being an upper bound, reduces $\preceq$ to a preorder.  Another way of looking at this, is that the entire chain $x_0\preceq x_1,\preceq x_2\ldots \to x_0$ needs to be in equality.

I don't know how to resolve this problem to show that $x'$ is a maximal element of $\overline X$.

**Question**

How do I build out the structure further to show $x'$ is either a maximal element, or an element within a larger maximal object?

**Attempt**

- Does creating a further equivalence relation that sets $x_n\sim x_{n+1}$ in each chain, and then let $\preceq$ act on $X/{\sim}$ instead, resolve this problem?
- I have another idea, that I take the "identity" chain $x'$ and divide every chain by it to get $\dfrac{x_n}{x'_n}$ to give an isomorphic set of chains which converge to the constant chain $1,1,1\ldots$.

Do either of these look reasonable?

Comment: So you just have countable limit?  Anyway, ZL merely say maximal element exists, but doesn't actually give you one.

Comment: @user10354138 I guess. I've not heard that term before but I assume it means what it's obviously interpreted as.

Comment: It looks like you are defining $x'=\overline{X}\setminus X$. So $x'$ is a subset of $\overline{X}$ and it's not clear what is meant by asking whether it is a maximal element of $\overline{X}$. You later describe $x'$ as a chain consisting of elements $x'_n$, and by deducing that there is a limit $x_0$ it would seem that each $x'_n$ must be in $X$ so that you can apply your initial assumption. If so, then $x'$ is treated like a subset of $X$ (but the definition above forces it to be disjoint from $X$). Perhaps you can provide a specific example of what you mean?

Comment: @halrankard Let $x'_n:n\in\Bbb N$ be the chain $x'$, satisfying $x_0\preceq x_1\preceq x_2,\ldots$. Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0$.  You seem to deduce that this implies $x'\subset X$ but this is not implied. Or at least I don't see why it would be.

Comment: To be clear, I'm suggesting that it implies $x_n\in X$ for all $n$. And I'm saying this because if $x'$ is not a chain of elements *from $X$* then how do you know the limit $x_0$ exists? (btw in your comment you have $x_0$ in the chain and equal to the limit...is this intentional?)

Comment: @halrankard yes, $x_0$ in the chain and the limit of the chain is the whole point of the question.  This "fly in the ointment" means the limit of $\preceq$ is a preorder whereas $\preceq$ itself is a partial order. And Zorn's lemma needs the limit of $\preceq$ (i.e. upper bounds), to be an order rather than merely a preorder.

Comment: Ok let's say I have an $\mathbb{N}$-indexed chain $x_0\preceq x_1 \preceq x_2\ldots$. What does it mean precisely to say that this chain has a limit in $\overline{X}$?

Comment: @halrankard Let $Q=\Bbb Z[\frac16]^+/\langle2,3\rangle$ where $\langle2,3\rangle=\{2^m3^n:m,n\in\Bbb Z\}$ and $\Bbb Z[\frac16]^+$ is the positive dyadic and ternary rationals. Let $x'=\langle2,3\rangle\cdot\left(1+\frac{2^{6n}-1}{3\cdot2^{6n}}:n\in\Bbb N\right)$ then $x_0=\langle2,3\rangle$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\langle2,3\rangle$.

Comment: I ask for a rigorous definition in the context of your general question, not an example. $(\overline{X},\preceq)$ is an arbitrary partially ordered set, $x_0\preceq x_1\preceq\ldots$ is a countable chain, and $x$ is an element of $\overline{X}$. What is the definition of $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x$?

Comment: @halrankard let $\overline X$ be a metric space such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=x_0$ in $\overline X$

Comment: Your question says nothing of metric spaces. It seems this discussion is going nowhere. I had been optimistic that there was an interesting question here, but it is unclear. Your first sentence says "every chain has a limit in $\overline{X}$". But the notion of "limit" is not defined. Then you ask if $x'$ is a maximal element of $\overline{X}$. But $x'$ is defined to be a subset of $\overline{X}$, not an element of $\overline{X}$. So it is unclear what the question even means. That's all I have. If the question is edited to clarify these issues then I will delete these comments.

Comment: @halrankard it's just that there's very little restriction on the definition of convergence, that's all. I'm sorry the question disappoints. I agree there is a good question in here, I maybe just can't express it well. FWIW I'm pretty sure the attempts I give in the question (which are largely the same) are the right answer - which I'm going to attempt now.

Comment: @halrankard FWIW, this is the specific application: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3769897/ in which I have "fixed" the maximal chain containing $x'$ by dividing everything throughout by that chain.

Comment: You may have as much or as little restriction on the definition of convergence as you wish. But there still must be a definition. If you mean to leave it open for interpretation then there are very natural interpretations under which your question trivially has a negative answer. I just looked briefly at the new question in the link, but if you are unable to provide rigorous definitions and clarification in the elementary context of this question, then I doubt that carrying on in the context of a major open problem will be very productive.

Comment: @halrankard yes, I did mean to leave it as unrestricted as declaring $X$ a metric space and saying that chains converge.  I think the answer given below is correct in giving the trivially negative answer.  However I did push for a little more, i.e. what conditions might be added to give a positive answer.

Comment: @halrankard I've added the statement that $\overline X$ is a topological space and I think that is all I intended to ask about, something as general as that. I'm pretty sure the answer I propose in the question, i.e. to set all elements of $x'$ equivalent via an equivalent relation is one acceptable solution. The solution I elected in the end was to divide all chains by $x'$ to turn $x'$ into the constant sequence and that appears to have worked... in fact in so doing it fixed another problem I was wrestling with.

Comment: You still have not addressed the part of your question that is the most confusing. $x'$ is defined to be a subset of $\overline{X}$. **What does it mean to say that $x'$ is a maximal *element* of $\overline{X}$?**

Comment: Other comments: If "limit" in the first sentence is meant in the topological sense, then you should *first* say that $\overline{X}$ is a topological space. Also, right now, you do not specify any relationship between $X$ and $\overline{X}$. Presumably $X\subseteq\overline{X}$ and $\prec$ on $X$ extends $\prec$ on $\overline{X}$. *Please do not respond to these issues in the comments. Edit the main post to address them. Focus on the main question in my last comment. But I also suggest proofreading your entire question toward making things more rigorous and clear.*

Comment: @halrankard thanks. I'm just getting to grips with the fact you're alluding to, which is that the topological limit point of a chain is not necessarily a least upper bound in the order. (You're right, I had wrongly assumed it was).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is false with only countable limits.

**Example**: Let $\lambda$ be a limit ordinal with cofinality $>\omega$ (e.g. $\lambda=\omega_1$) and glue the half-ray $\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ to the bottom, identifying $0$.  This is our $\bar{X}$.  Let $X=\bar{X}-\{-1\}$.  Then every countable chain in $X$ either lies completely in $\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ so has a limit there, or eventually in $\lambda$.  But $\lambda$ itself is a chain without maximal element, and any countable limit of ordinals below $\lambda$ is $<\lambda$ by supposition.

Comment: Thanks. I think this will add insight for me (so please don't delete)... as I want to re-read a few times and think on it for a while.  But notwithstanding that, I think I was also asking for more... i.e. I accept already ZL fails here, because "upper bounds" is like a closure of $\preceq$, and that is only a preorder on $\overline X$ whereas a partial order is needed.  But the "extra" I ask for... is how might I circumvent this problem, given that I know $x'$ is part of some maximal object and I want to prove that fact.  In particular, suppose the chain containing $x'$ is the maximal chain.

Comment: What is the significance of puncturing $\Bbb R$ here? I.e. by deleting $\{1\}$.